# Logistic Regression sklearn with categorical Output

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, classification, logistic-regression

i have to train a model with logistic Regression in sklearn. I saw everywhere that the outcome has to be binary but my label is good, bad or normal. I have 12 features and i don't know how can i deal with three Labels ? I am very thankful for every answer

Comment: @ShreyanshAgarwal scikit-learn is explicitly mentioned in the title, body, and tags.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I recommended him as he is new, adding Python in the tag will make it more clear and will increase the reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Multinomial Logistic Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression)**.
In python, you can modify your Logistic Regression code as:

```py
LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial').fit(X_train,y_train)
```

You can see [Logistic Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) documentation in Scikit-Learn for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's called as one-vs-all Classification or Multi class classification.

From [sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression):

> In the multiclass case, the training algorithm uses the one-vs-rest (OvR) scheme if the ‘multi_class’ option is set to ‘ovr’, and uses the cross-entropy loss if the ‘multi_class’ option is set to ‘multinomial’. (Currently the ‘multinomial’ option is supported only by the ‘lbfgs’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’ and ‘newton-cg’ solvers.)

Code example:

```py
# Authors: Tom Dupre la Tour <tom.dupre-la-tour@m4x.org>
# License: BSD 3 clause

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# make 3-class dataset for classification
centers = [[-5, 0], [0, 1.5], [5, -1]]
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, centers=centers, random_state=40)
transformation = [[0.4, 0.2], [-0.4, 1.2]]
X = np.dot(X, transformation)

for multi_class in ('multinomial', 'ovr'):
    clf = LogisticRegression(solver='sag', max_iter=100, random_state=42,
                             multi_class=multi_class).fit(X, y)

    # print the training scores
    print("training score : %.3f (%s)" % (clf.score(X, y), multi_class))
```

Check for full code example: [Plot multinomial and One-vs-Rest Logistic Regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_logistic_multinomial.html)